# Javascript persist variable that stores nodes after those nodes are deleted

Tags: javascript

I came across a very simple issue (but one I'm not sure can be resolved) in JavaScript. I have a variable in which I store nodes that have a certain class. What I want to do is delete these nodes from the DOM, but keep them in the variable. But since apparently the variables stores references, once these nodes are deleted the variable becomes empty.

Here's a code sample:

```
const modules = document.getElementsByClassName("drag-container");
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("drag-container")[0].parentElement;
while (parent.firstChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
}
//here the modules variable is empty
```

Is it possible to maintain the modules variable after the nodes are deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, and that is *live*, therefore if you remove the nodes, they also get removed from that collection. You can clone that collection into an array though:

```
  const modules = Array.from(/*HTMLCollection here */);
```

Comment: A simple and functional answer, thank you. Didn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the HTMLCollection array (modules) by using the new spread syntax.

```
const copiedModules = [... modules];
```

I hope this helped.